# Google Analytics custom variables still showing up in User Defined

Tags: javascript, variables, google-analytics

I recently updated the Google Analytics code in my web app to use the new _setCustomVar syntax for custom variables, and removed the old code snippet with the deprecated _setVar method.

Variables set with the new syntax show up in the Google Analytics web interface under Audience > Custom > Custom Variables.  I see all the custom variables I set in this section, as expected.

However, I'm also still seeing some information logged in the User Defined section (Audience > Custom > User Defined).  As far as I can tell, no data should be appearing here, as this is where GA displays the variables set using the old _setVar code.  Yet, even though the change was implemented weeks ago, we're still seeing data in this section.

Has anyone else experienced this?  What's the expected behavior when switching to custom variables?

I have grepped the entire codebase for _setVar, and it doesn't appear anywhere.  The JS snippet is included directly in the base template file, which is rendered by Jinja, so I don't think JS caching is an issue.

Here's the snippet I'm using:

```
    #if is_production:
    <script type="text/javascript">
      // Google analytics
      var _gaq = _gaq || [];
      _gaq.push(['_setAccount', '############']);

      #if {{ user }}:
        _gaq.push(['_setCustomVar', 1, 'company', '{{ company_name }}', 3 ]);
      #endif

      _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

      (function() {
        var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
        ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
      })();
    </script>
    #endif
```

Any ideas would be helpful!  Thanks!

Comment: I'm about 90% sure that visitors who already had visitor scoped events pop for them under the old code will continue to show up there, until their cookies are erased.

Comment: Good point, thanks!  I'll see if I can manually clear those old cookies somehow.